# angularjs controllerAs register $destroy

Tags: angularjs

Documentation of angular says, to execute code to cleanup when the controller is destroyed, one should register for the $destroy event on the scope.

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() { ... } );
```

However, when you use the controllerAs syntax, you don't have access to $scope. How would you register the $destroy event ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just because you use the `controllerAs` syntax, it doesn't mean there is no `$scope` or that you can't use it.

In fact, all the `controllerAs` does is add the controller's `this` on the `$scope` (under the specified name). E.g.:

```
ng-controller="SomeCtrl as ctrl"
```

will implicitly do this:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function () {
    this.value = 'something';
    ...

    // Angular will implicitly so something equivalent to:
    // $scope.ctrl = this;
}
```

---

So, there is nothing stopping you from using the `$scope` (it is actually quite useful for things like `$watch`ing stuff and sending/listening for events):

```
<!-- In the VIEW -->
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl as ctrl">
    Some value: {{ctrl.value}}
    <button ng-click="ctrl.doSomething()">Some action</button>
</div>
```

```
/* In the CONTROLLER */
.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.value = 'some value';
    this.doSomething = function () { ... };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        // So some clean-up...
    });
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/P9JdL/)**.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible without injecting $scope:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.$onDestroy = function(){
        console.log( 'destroying....' );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know there is one dependency `$element`, if you inject that in controller will give you the DOM where you have `ng-controller` directive placed. So inject $element inside your controller & then place listener over it like below

```
$element.on('$destroy', function(){
   //write clean up code here
})
```